# When is the augmentation ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ principal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let

$$I_G = \left\{\sum_{g \in G} a_gg \in \mathbb{Z}[G] : \sum_{g \in G}a_g = 0\right\}$$

be the augmentation ideal of the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$. If $G$ is cyclic, then $I_G$ is a principal ideal generated by $g - 1$ for $g$ a generator of $G$.

> Is it true that if $I_G$ is principal, then $G$ must be cyclic?

I know that $I_G$ is generated by $g - 1$ for $g \in G$. If we assume that $x = \sum_{g \in G}a_gg \in I_G$ is a generator of $I_G$, then for each $g_0 \in G$ there is some $\sum_{g \in G}b_gg$ such that

$$\sum_{G \in G}a_gg \cdot \sum_{g \in G}b_gg = g_0 - 1.$$

This gives us a system of linear equations over $\mathbb{Z}$ which should have a solution if and only if the resulting matrix has rank $\vert G \vert - 1$. The columns of this matrix are all permutations of each other, but I'm not sure how to connect the rank of the matrix to whether or not $G$ is cyclic (if this is even true).

Comment: Is "principal ideal" to be understood in the noncommutative two-sided sense (i.e., it consists of all possible sums of $r\left(g-1\right)s$ expressions)?

Comment: If so, the answer is "no". Let $G$ be any simple finite group, and let $g$ be any non-identity element. The conjugates of $g$ then generate the entire group $G$ (since the group they generate must be normal in $G$). Thus, every element of $G$ can be written as a product $u_1 g u_1^{-1} \cdot u_2 g u_2^{-1} \cdot \cdots \cdot u_k g u_k^{-1}$. Hence, the principal two-sided ideal generated by $g-1$ is the entire $I_G$ (since $u_1 g u_1^{-1} \cdot u_2 g u_2^{-1} \cdot \cdots \cdot u_k g u_k^{-1} \equiv u_1 u_1^{-1} \cdot u_2 u_2^{-1} \cdot \cdots \cdot u_k u_k^{-1} = 1 \mod I_G$).

Comment: Also, even if you want a principal left ideal or a principal right ideal, you won't get very far by looking at ranks of matrices. In fact, if $G$ is **any** finite group, then the augmentation ideal of $\mathbb{Q}\left[G\right]$ is the principal left ideal generated by the single element $u$, where $u = 1 - \dfrac{1}{\left|G\right|} \sum\limits_{g \in G} g$. If this is not to happen with $\mathbb{Z}\left[G\right]$, then the reason must be something about integers (as opposed to rational numbers). But the rank of a matrix doesn't know much about integers.

Comment: On the other hand, if you assume that $I_G$ is the principal left ideal generated by $g-1$ for some $g \in G$ (as opposed to by some random element), then you can indeed conclude that $G$ is cyclic and generated by this $g$. I'll leave the nice graph-theoretic proof to you.